# Using sinon mocks with nodeunit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, sinon, nodeunit

I'm learning to use sinon with [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit), specifically to do mocking.  The [recommended approach](http://sinonjs.org/nodeunit/) is to use [sinon-nodeunit](https://github.com/cjohansen/sinon-nodeunit).  According to [the documentation](http://sinonjs.org/nodeunit/#mocks), mocks should be available via the `mock` method of the `test` parameter to each test function.

However, this doesn't seem to work.  If I run `nodeunit` on a file containing the following —

```
require('sinon-nodeunit');

exports['test sinon-nodeunit'] = function (test) {
    mock = test.mock({});
    test.done();
};
```

— I get this:

```
$ nodeunit test/test-sinon-nodeunit.js 

test-sinon-nodeunit.js
✖ test sinon-nodeunit

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mock'
    at /home/malkovich/test/test-sinon-nodeunit.js:4:17
    at Object.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/lib/core.js:54:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/lib/core.js:90:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/deps/async.js:508:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/deps/async.js:118:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/deps/async.js:134:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/deps/async.js:507:9
    at Object.concatSeries (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/deps/async.js:147:23)
    at Object.runSuite (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/lib/core.js:79:11)
    at Object.runModule (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/nodeunit/0.5.1/package/lib/core.js:114:13)


FAILURES: 1/1 assertions failed (84ms)
```

I've installed current versions of both `sinon` (1.1.1) and `sinon-nodeunit` (0.1.2) via `npm install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require.path was removed in node 0.5.x and higher, which sinon-nodeunit uses. Christian Johansen just pushed a change in sinon-nodeunit which should be compatible with node 0.6.2 (and 0.5.x-series) which should fix this... It's already available on sinon-nodeunits github page, still hasnt hit npm though...

update: should be mentioned that sinon-nodeunit has been discontinued, as the creator is full focused on BusterJS which IMHO is a much better framework.