# Over-riding an asynchronous function in an Express unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, nodeunit

I've been battling with writing some express unit tests for my app most of today. I have an asynchronous function that does some app setup in app.js, it reads lots of files so it takes a while. Running the app isn't a problem, unit testing is though because when the tests run, the setup hasn't completed yet.

So I figured I'd stub out the async function, get it to call a re-defined async function that doesn't complete the unit test setUp until a callback has been run.

The issue is that when the re-defined function runs, the app instance that it gets passed, hasn't had all the setup done, even though the test passes the app into the setup. It seems as though sinon.callsArgWith sets up a closure around the arguments so that when the function runs, it has the args with pre-setup state.

I'm also using proxyquire to make sure that I get fresh loads of modules between test runs (using noPreserveCache).

The redefined function is passed in the options argument, and sinon looks for it and runs it, I think this is how it's supposed to be done, I read the documentation 20 times and couldn't find any other way to get the code to run (is that the correct way to use sinon?)

The express app (v4) has the following structure:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── lib
│   ├── async_function.js
│   ├── error_handlers.js
│   ├── helpers.js
│   └── options.js
├── package.json
└── test
    └── test.js
```

www:

```
var
  app   = require( '../app' ),
  server;

app.set( 'port', process.env.PORT || 3000 );

server = app.listen( app.get( 'port' ), function () {
  console.log( "Express server listening on port " + server.address().port );
});
```

app.js:

```
var
  async_function = require( './lib/async_function' ),
  express        = require( 'express' ),
  path           = require( 'path' ),
  app            = express(),
  options        = require( './lib/options' ),
  setupErrorHandlers = require( './lib/error_handlers' );
```

;

```
// do some app setup stuff
app.set( 'views', path.join( __dirname, 'views' ) );
app.set( 'view engine', 'hogan' );
app.disable( "x-powered-by" );

async_function( app, options, function ( err ) {
  if ( err ) console.log( "Error: " + err );
  setupErrorHandlers( app );
});

module.exports = app;
```

async_function.js:

```
module.exports = function ( app, options, cb ) {
  setTimeout( function () {
    if ( app.result ) {
      app.result += options.arg1 + options.arg2;
    }
    else {
      app.result = options.arg1 + options.arg2;
    }
    console.log( "async_function.js: app.result: " + app.result );
    cb();
  }, 10000 );
};
```

options.js:

```
module.exports = {
  arg1: "qwertyuiop",
  arg2: "asdfghjkl"
};
```

test.js:

```
var
  nodeunit = require( 'nodeunit' ),
  express  = require( 'express' ),
  helpers  = require( '../lib/helpers' );

exports[ 'stubbing a non returning async function with a custom function' ] =         nodeunit.testCase({
  setUp: function ( callback ) {
    var async_path = '../lib/async_function';
    this.app = express();
    var options = {
      arg1: "zxcvbnm",
      arg2: "1234567890"
    };
    helpers.setupTestExpressApp( async_path, this.app, options, callback );
  },

  tearDown: function ( callback ) {
    delete this.app;
    callback();
  },

  'test1': function ( t ) {
    t.expect( 2 );
    t.ok( ( this.app.result !== undefined ), 'async_function produced a result' );
    t.equal( this.app.result, 'zxcvbnm1234567890', 'custom async function was called' );
    t.done();
  },

  'test2': function ( t ) {
    t.expect( 2 );
    t.ok( ( this.app.result !== undefined ), 'async_function produced a result' );
    t.equal( this.app.result, 'zxcvbnm1234567890', 'custom async function was called' );
    t.done();
  }
});
```

helpers.js:

```
var
  proxyquire = require( 'proxyquire' ).noPreserveCache(),
  sinon      = require( 'sinon' );

var setupTestExpressApp = function ( async_path, app, options, callback ) {
  var
    options, app, cb,
    async_function, async_function_stub, redefined_async_function;

  // Get a fresh copy of the async_function
  async_function = proxyquire( async_path, { } );

  // Create a stub
  async_function_stub = sinon.stub();

  cb = function ( err ) {
    if ( err ) console.log( "Error: " + err );
    console.log( "Setup complete redefined" );
    callback();
  };

  // Create the re-defined function
  redefined_async_function = function ( app, options, cb ) {
    async_function( app, options, cb );
  };

  // Instruct the stub to use the custom function with the prepared args
  async_function_stub.callsArgWith( 1, app, options, cb );

  // Run the app setup, passing in the stub, the express app and sneaking in the
  // redefined function in the options arg
  app = proxyquire( '../app', {
    './lib/async_function': async_function_stub,
    app: app,
    './lib/options': redefined_async_function
  });
};

module.exports = {
  setupTestExpressApp : setupTestExpressApp
};
```

Is there something obvious / obscure that I've missed? Or some easier way that I'm not aware of?

I imagine there would be, it sure seems like a lot of effort just to run a few tests on an express app.

I would really appreciate some help with this, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sinon mocks with nodeunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104796/using-sinon-mocks-with-nodeunit)